# html elements of flash audio player

Tags: javascript, flash

I use flash audio player like:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="/audio/audio-player.js"></script> 
<script language="JavaScript" src="/audio/swfobject.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">  
     AudioPlayer.setup("/audio/player.swf", {});
</script>
<p id="audio"> <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/">Get Adobe Flash Player</a>.</p>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     AudioPlayer.embed("audio", {
     soundFile: "/audio/test.mp3", 
     });
</script>
```

and I want to use hotkeys for audio play, so I need to know html element id for play button.
Are there any ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

of course there is, check the link.
[How to interact with Flash via Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319526/how-to-interact-with-flash-via-javascript)