# How to interact with Flash via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, flash, video, streaming

At this moment there is a very basic flash project that connects to a rtmp server and streams video&audio from webcam. It creates a stream from a user with a certain name.

Also in same project there is an input for a stream name that other entity can stream. Therefore you get Skype alike video-chat with flash.

In flash I can control when I want to start publishing own stream and when  want to play someone else's stream.

I am trying to figure out how I can control Flash Functions (StartPublish, StartStream, etc) via Javascript.

I am looking at http://osflash.org/projects/flashjs and would like to know if I am on right path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

The ExternalInterface class is designed specifically for this purpose.  It's a relatively simple class for exposing actionscript functions to JS or vice versa.  I recently implemented it in an audio player my team developed to have an HTML formatted tracklist trigger play and stop events.

Essentially, you can make your code first check against `ExternalInterface.available` to make sure the container has an external interface (IE in a browser window with javascript and not just running from flash player.)  From there, you can use `addCallback` to designate a function that can then be called on the flash applet's container.

You can then call it using the typical javascript - just access the method off of the container using getElementByID or whatever selector flavor you prefer if you're using a framework.

Make sure your embed method allows script access to the flash applet as well.