# HTML5 Webaudio: Capture audio data from speaker

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

is it possible to capture users default audio output by html5 webaudio features?

For Example: The User watches to an embedded YouTube Video (musst not necessarily be youtube). Is it possible to capture the audio he's listening to?

Thx for your help!

Comment: If you know the `<audio>` or `video` tag you want to listen to, you can use the [Web Audio API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/) (currently supported in Chrome, in progress in FF). In particular see "How can I process sound from `audio` and `video` tags?" on [this HTML5 Rocks page](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/01/Web-Audio-FAQ). If the sound is not coming from an `<audio>` or `<video>` element (e.g., it comes from a plugin, or a program totally external to the browser), you cannot capture that sound from the browser.

Comment: Thx for your help! I tried to capture the audio from a flash container. So there is no chance to do this with html5?

Comment: Correct; as far as I know, that is not possible for JavaScript to capture the audio of a Flash object. (You might be able to monitor the Flash plugin object with *your own* Flash plugin object, but I don't know anything about that.) The Flash object could [proactively offer some JavaScript functions to control it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319526/how-to-interact-with-flash-via-javascript), but I very seriously doubt YouTube would offer functions on their Flash objects to capture audio.